# ¿Como hago para que mi header fixed no se superponga a las imagenes?

Tags: html, css, web

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>TITLE UNICOLOR</TITLE>

<STYLE>
    *{padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; text-decoration:none; 
color:inherit;}
    HEADER{width:100%; height:8%; border-bottom:1px solid #E0E0E0; border- 
top:1px solid #E0E0E0; position:fixed;}
    HEADER UL{display:table; margin:0 auto;}
    HEADER LI{float:left; padding:30px; font-family:Verdana; font- 
weight:600; font-size:14px;}
    MAIN{width:50%; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%;}
        img.MAIN_IMAGES{max-width:100%;}
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <HEADER>
    <UL><LI><A href='#'>UPDATES</A></LI><LI><A href='#'>CATEGORIES</A></LI> 
 <LI><A href='#'>STUDIOS</A></LI><LI><A href='#'>MODELS</A></LI></UL>
    </HEADER></A>

    <MAIN>
        <IMG src='1.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='2.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='3.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='4.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='5.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='6.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='7.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='8.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
        <IMG src='9.jpg' class='MAIN_IMAGES'/>
    </MAIN>

    <ASIDE>

    </ASIDE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que las imágenes estén sobre el header puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
HEADER{
    width:100%; 
    height:8%; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #E0E0E0; 
    border-top:1px solid #E0E0E0; 
    position:fixed; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    z-index: 1;
}
img.MAIN_IMAGES{
    max-width:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Adicional a lo que ya tenias agregué la propiedad **z-index** que permite cambiar el "orden de las capas" pero hay que tener en cuenta que esta propiedad se debe usar en compañía de la propiedad **position** con los valores relative, fixed o obsolute.

[Aqui más información de z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)